# How start flyway manually in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

How can I start flyway manually with Spring Boot? Because I have 2 dbs in my application, so after Springboot load the properties and before connect to DB, I need to run the flyway from my 2 dbs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to start flyway manually, but run it on two databases. Here is how:

create two Datasources and mark one as @Primary, the other (should be a bean) as @FlywayDataSource.
When flyway runs, it will automatically run on both data sources. see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup

Answer (score -1):

You can use flyway maven plugin to populate your databases.

You can either have two properties file for each database and execute flyway using `mvn -Dflyway.configFile=myConfig.properties`

Or

you can provide the db properties while executing maven like `mvn -Dflyway.user=myUser -Dflyway.schemas=schema1,schema2 -Dflyway.placeholders.keyABC=valueXYZ`

But please note that you have to execute flyway maven task twice. Each time for one database. Like,

```
$mvn -Dflyway.configFile=db1.properties compile migrate
$mvn -Dflyway.configFile=db2.properties compile migrate
```

Refer https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/ for more information.

If you are fine with this maven approach you don't need spring to do flyway migration.

Comment: This don`t work.. because I update my client db, when I send one .war to update the app. but tks